# Setting property value for New-ScheduledTaskTrigger

Tags: powershell, object, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

I am trying out to create a new scheduled task using PowerShell, but I can't change one of the properties: `Repetition   Property   CimInstance#Instance Repetition {get;set;}`

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute powershell.exe -Argument "-c test.ps1"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -daily -at 10am -DaysInterval 1 
$trigger.DaysInterval = (New-TimeSpan -hours 1)
$trigger.enabled = $true
$trigger.Repetition = (New-TimeSpan -Days 1) #Failing with error

.....

Exception setting "Repetition": "The adapter cannot set the value of property "Repetition"."
At line:1 char:1
+ $trigger.Repetition = 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValue
```

Are there any parameters associated with `New-ScheduledTaskAction` that I can use to change these properties via cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values can be set, but not with `New-ScheduledTaskAction`. The repetition interval for `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` is associated with the parameter set name of Once. It's not associated with the Daily parameter set.

To use those parameters, you'd need a different trigger defined with `-Once` instead of `-Daily`. For example:

```
$hourly = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1)
$days = (New-TimeSpan -Days 30)
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 10am -RepetitionInterval $hourly -RepetitionDuration $days
```

That would define a trigger that started at 10am, and triggers again every hour for 30 days.